# Execute python program with multiple files - Python - Bash

Tags: python, bash

I have hundreds of XML files and I would like to parse it into CSV files. I already code this program.
To execute the python program I use this command (on VScode MS):

```
python ConvertXMLtoCSV.py -i Alarm120.xml -o Alarm120.csv
```

My question is, how change this script to integrate a sort of for loop to execute this program for each xml files ?

---

**UPDATE**

If my files and folders are organized like in the picture:

[image]

I tried this and execute the file .bat in windows10 but it does nothing:

```
#!/bin/bash
for xml_file in XML_Files/*.xml
do
   csv_file=${xml_file/.xml/.csv}
   python ConvertXMLtoCSV.py -i XML_Files/$xml_file -o CSV_Files/$csv_file
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion, it appears that you wish to use an external script so as to leave the original `ConvertXMLtoCSV.py` script unmodified (as required by other projects), but that although you tagged `bash` in the question, it turned out that you were not in fact able to use `bash` to invoke `python` when you tried it in your setup.

This being the case, it is possible to adapt Rolv Apneseth's answer so that you do the looping in Python, but inside a *separate* script (let's suppose that this is called `convert_all.py`), which then runs the unmodified `ConvertXMLtoCSV.py` as an external process.  This way, the `ConvertXMLtoCSV.py` will still be set up to process only one file each time it is run.

To call an external process, you could either use `os.system` or `subprocess.Popen`, so here are two options.

Using `os.system`:

```
import os
import sys

directory_path = sys.argv[1]

for file in os.listdir(directory_path):
    if file.endswith(".xml"):
        csv_name = file.replace(".xml", ".csv")
        os.system(f'python ConvertXMLtoCSV.py -i {file} -o {csv_name}')
```

note: for versions of python too old to support f-strings, that last line could be changed to

```python
        os.system('python ConvertXMLtoCSV.py -i {} -o {}'.format(file,csv_name))
```

Using `subprocess.Popen`:

```
import subprocess
import sys

directory_path = sys.argv[1]

for file in os.listdir(directory_path):
    if file.endswith(".xml"):
        csv_name = file.replace(".xml", ".csv")
        p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'ConvertXMLtoCSV.py',
                              '-i', file,
                              '-o', csv_name])
        p.wait()
```

You could then run it using some command such as:

```
python convert_all.py C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/myfolder
```

or whatever the folder is where you have the XML files.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally the for loop would be included inside your ConvertXMLtoCSV.py itself. You can use this to find all xml files in a given directory:

```
for file in os.listdir(directory_path):
    if file.endswith(".xml"):
        # And here you can do your conversion
```

You could change the arguments given to the script to be the path of the directory the xml files are located in and the path for an output folder for the .csv files. For renaming, you can leave the files with the same name but give the .csv extension. i.e.

```
csv_name = file.replace(".xml", ".csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your Python script as-is (process one file), and add the looping externally in `bash`, you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash
for xml_file in *.xml
do
   csv_file=${xml_file/.xml/.csv}
   python ConvertXMLtoCSV.py -i $xml_file -o $csv_file
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I tried it again. Can you analyze my update please.

Comment: You tagged `bash` so I wrote a bash script, assuming that you had already done what is necessary to run bash under windows. If this is not the case then you might need to install CygWin or similar. It is not a script that you can run as a Windows `.bat` file.  If you can't run bash under Windows, then you can put your looping in the Python instead, as shown in the other answer.

Comment: When I execute the code on cygwin I have  "./Alarms_Script.sh: line 5: /cygdrive/c/Users/antho/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python: Permission denied"

Comment: @ThonyNadhir Sorry I don't know why you are getting permission denied when trying to run Python via CygWin. It looks like it might be necessary to install Python under Cygwin - https://wiki.usask.ca/display/MESH/Running+Python+from+the+Cygwin+Terminal . Again, I was assuming from the fact that you tagged both `bash` and `python` that you had already got a setup in which these two would interoperate. However, if this is not the case then you do not *need* to use `bash`, because Python can do the looping for you, and what's in the other answer should be sufficient information on how to do that.

Comment: @ThonyNadhir I guess that you do also have an option of writing an external script to do the looping (so as to leave your ConvertXMLtoCSV.py unchanged), but writing that script in python. I could provide an example of this as another answer if you want, but before I do that, please can you confirm whether in python you can do `import os` followed by `os.system("python -c 'print(2+2)'")` - it should print `4` (possibly followed by `0`). This will test whether python can call python as an external process. **If** you can first confirm this, then I can provide an example of the full script.

Comment: Yeah, I use this program for several projects, so the less I change it the better I am. I tried your code with `os.system` and I have directly `0`. Great, thanks for your help !

Comment: But do you have the `4`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222584/discussion-between-thony-nadhir-and-alani).